# Powershell - checking for new files

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

This code seems to only work if a 'new' file is created. It seems it doesn't accept a file copied into the folder, which is what I need. We have an application which processes .csv files and puts them into a folder which I want to monitor via a scheduled task each day. Anything I can try to change in this code?

```
Param (
[string]$Path = "C:\Users\MG\Desktop\ScanFolder"
)                                                                        
$File = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where { $_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) }                                                                           
If ( $File ) {                                                          
Write-Output "Error File Found"                                              
}                                                                         
else { Write-Output "Nothing Found" }
```

Comment: Using a [FileSystemWatcher](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/09/24/changes-to-a-folder-using-powershell.aspx) might help as this can be configured to monitor a folder (and subfolders) for file changes, including copied files.

Comment: What is doing the copy of the file into this directory? I used `Copy-Item` and `LastWriteTime` was unchanged from the original file location. Both `LastAccessTime` and `CreationTime` were updated to the current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test the value of `.CreationTime` / `.CreationTimeUtc` instead:

- for newly *created* files, it will reflect the creation time.
- for newly *copied* files, it will reflect the time the file was copied to the folder (even though that will be more recent than the file's `.LastWriteTime` value).

Applied to your code:

```
Param (
  [string] $Path = "C:\Users\MG\Desktop\ScanFolder"
)                                                                        

$file = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where { $_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) }                                                                           

If ($file) {                                                          
  "Error File Found"                                              
} else { 
  "Nothing Found" 
}
```